# How to check which shipping rate is set in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there a way to check if a certain shipping rate is set for a product? I am trying to display an Icon on the products page only when a specific shipping rate is set for the specific product. Something like this:

```
if(shippingRate === highCostShipping) {
  ExecuteFunction();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html load the product into this class and check the shipping class and compare it to your shipping class. Simple.

Comment: You can't check if a shipping rate (or method) is set for a product, what you can check for products is only if a shipping method is applied to it using [`get_shipping_class_id()`  `WC_Product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_shipping_class_id) method … **Remember that Shipping rates depend on the customer Shipping Zone and on the chosen Shipping Method…**